# Wso2 Scim Shema UI

Tags: wso2, scim, wso2-identity-server

So reading up on the [docs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Extensible+SCIM+User+Schemas+With+WSO2+Identity+Server#6fbb974d4297493792fdaf32aa96ec90) about Scim Api I see that it shows some UI that i can seem to be able to access from somewhere.

[image]

How do access this UI or how do i enable it if i have to?

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that resides in WSO2 IS. It's just some JSON editor demonstrating the SCIM user object representation.